# Difficult in debugging Google Drive App

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am build programs by Google Script, and can use its debugger well.

Now, I am building my 1st Google Drive App. The normal operation flow is:
User select files in Google Drive and then call my App => Selected files are passed to my App as State Parameter => doGet() to create/open Client's HTML => User select options in that HTML and submit => Server receive the submitted form and do somethings.

However, debugging Drive App for me is difficult than normal Web Apps and Container-bounded Apps, due to its "State Parameter". I need to publish the Drive App first, and then debug Client's HTML & JScript by Javascript console and Server's GScript by Google Script Editor separately. Is it normal for Web programming? Or have I missed anything? Can I simulate the "State Parameter" for testing, so that I don't need to debug AFTER publish (even using test link) ?

N.B. Since above flow is clear enough, I haven't post demo code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run an Apps Script in development mode.  You can make infinite number of changes to your Apps Script, run it in development mode, and test it without deploying the App.  You will see "dev" on end of the URL:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/Aew678900-wdfgyj/dev
```

When you open up the Publish Your Web App Window, click the:

> Test web app for your latest code.

To run it in development mode.

Comment: Hi Sandy, thanks for your comment. I know that mode. Publish outside is not the key point. The key point is: If I initiate the App from Drive as normal user, I cannot run in debug mode. If I run debug mode insider Script Editor, I need the input of state parameters. Temporarily, I can just programmatically and manually insert values in the very start of the module to simulate it. Don't know if there is any better solution.

Comment: So you want an user who does not own the Apps Script to be able to debug your code?  Like a collaborative effort?